# Do I need to decant my 1st stage yeast starter, prior to adding 2nd stage wort solution?

Tags: yeast-starters

I’m making a lager.

I need to propagate the yeast in two stages to reach the target cell count.

Should I decant the spent wort from the first stage before i add the freshly boiled (and cooled) DME solution for the second stage?

Will not decanting result in off in final beer.

I will however, decant after the 2nd stage.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large enough vessel I guess you can omit decanting the first starter.  But you should decant at least in the end because that wort will have some level of oxidation off flavor in it and you don't want to add that to your beer.  Or at least limit it to some extent by partially decanting it.